# Test the color of patches in a radius

Tags: colors, netlogo, turtle-graphics, agent

I hope that you will can help me.

I try to test if one patch in radius 100 is yellow, but it's seem doesn't work.
Indeed, the condition seems to be always false, though it's not the case...

```
ifelse ([pcolor] of patches in-radius 100 = yellow)
[do something]
[do something else]
```

What is the solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the reason why your code isn't working: `[pcolor] of patches in-radius 100` is going to return the color of all the patches in that radius as list. For instance, that list probably looks something like

`[135 135 105 105 105 85 75 75 65 25 65 75 15]`

except way way longer. Those numbers are [NetLogo's color numbers](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#colors). `yellow` is number 45. So, basically, your conditional becomes

`[135 135 105 105 105 85 75 75 65 25 65 75 15] = 45`

Obviously, that big, huge list is not the same thing as a number, thus, you always get false.

To fix it, you want to use [`any?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#any), like this:

```
ifelse (any? patches in-radius 100 with [ pcolor = yellow ]) ...
```

`patches in-radius 100` gives you an agent-set of all the patches in that radius. `with [ pcolor = yellow ]` keeps only those patches that are yellow. `any?` just checks to see if there's anything in an agent-set.

Comment: So clear, so fast!
Thank you sooooo much!

(I can't "vote up" your post because of my reputation, too bad, sry :/ )

Comment: Glad it helped! No worries about voting up. Thanks for marking it correct though! Helps people keep track of what has been answered.